# Not able to delay the code inside a function that returns an array in Swift

Tags: swift, sorting, animation, delay

I am trying to visualize some sorting algorithms using Swift. I have seen a lot of these on web so I thought to create one using UIKit and Swift. 
I have been able to lay out bars of different (random) heights and when I press Sort button, it's sorts the height's array and creates a new sorted height and then creates the views again.

I am using merge sort and recursion to get this working. The recursive calls happen way too quickly to show the process of sorting. I would like to delay the `merge` function so that I can lay out bars as it merges the smaller components of arrays to create the sorted one.

This is the algo I am using for merge sorting (pretty standard stuff)

```
 func mergeSort(_ array: [Double]) -> [Double] {

    guard array.count > 1 else { return array}
    let midIndex = array.count / 2
    let leftPile =  mergeSort(Array(array[0..<midIndex]))
    let rightPile = mergeSort(Array(array[midIndex..<array.count]))

    return merge(leftPile: leftPile, rightPile: rightPile)
}

func merge(leftPile: [Double], rightPile: [Double]) -> [Double] {

     print("Left Pile: \(leftPile), rightPile: \(rightPile)")
      var leftIndex = 0
      var rightIndex = 0

      var orderedPile = [Double]()
      orderedPile.reserveCapacity(leftPile.count + rightPile.count)

        while leftIndex < leftPile.count && rightIndex < rightPile.count {
            if leftPile[leftIndex] < rightPile[rightIndex] {
                orderedPile.append(leftPile[leftIndex])
                leftIndex += 1
            }else if leftPile[leftIndex] > rightPile[rightIndex] {
                orderedPile.append(rightPile[rightIndex])
                rightIndex += 1
            }else {
                orderedPile.append(leftPile[leftIndex])
                leftIndex += 1

                orderedPile.append(rightPile[rightIndex])
                rightIndex += 1

            }

        }

      while leftIndex < leftPile.count {
        orderedPile.append(leftPile[leftIndex])
        leftIndex += 1
      }

      while rightIndex < rightPile.count {
        orderedPile.append(rightPile[rightIndex])
        rightIndex += 1
      }

        print("Sorted pile: \(orderedPile)")

       removeBarsFromSuperView()
       emptyBarArray()

        for (index, element) in orderedPile.enumerated() {
            self.layoutBars(index: index, element: element, color: .yellow)

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }   

    return orderedPile
}
```

The `orderedPile` returns the merged and sorted array, I want to layout bars of new heights according to the `orderPile` order. For this however, I need to delay or slow down execution.

I have used the `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter()` but since the function has to return the array, I can't do it while the code is run asynchronously in the background.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: You cannot delay from the sorting itself. Ideally split sorting and rendering into two separate things. The simplest solution is to keep an array of sorting steps, e.g. `let steps: [[Double]] = []`. Instead of rendering `orderedPile`, append `orderedPile` to  `steps`. After merge you will have an array with all the steps. Then you can run a `Timer` which will increase an index into that array (e.g. every 100ms ) and run layout.

Comment: Got it working. Thanks a lot! :)